# how to update document of many to many model

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Need help,
Let's say I have a model of 2 tables with relation of many to many . teachers and students.
I thought to save a document per student. to be able to search by student name but to be able to filter also by the teacher.
so I thought to create the document like that:

{
id: string 
studentName: string,
class: string
teachers: [teacherId1: string, teacherId2: string...]
...
}

but what should happens when I remove the teacher from some class, now I need to update all the class student's documents (and I have thousands, how much time it will take (my document itself is not huge)).
Is there an easy way to that? instead of updating a document one by one.
(let's say I have all the list of studentIds)
maybe my document model structure is not correct.
Is there any other good idea.
Thanks,

Comment: Some clarifying questions -
Your search document is modelled as

{ studentName: Edm.String, class: Edm.String, teachers:Edm.Collection(Edm.ComplexType) }

And presumably you want to delete one entity in the "teachers" complex collection from documents where it is present? Is that the question?

Also, do you know the document keys for the documents from which the "teacher" entity has to be deleted?

Comment: Please update your question to be a bit more clear.
Any way, Azure Cognitive Search allows batch operations (i.e., you don't need to update documents one-by-one)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents

As long as you know the document keys for the documents you want to update, you can refer to the link above and perform a batch update. Regarding the time it'll take, it's a factor of how much load your service is under and your service topology/SKU.